# PHP-Python - killing python process leads memory leak?

Tags: php, python, memory, memory-management

I am writing PHP-Python web application for a webApp scanner where web application is managed by PHP and scanning service is managed by python.  My question is if I kill a running python process with PHP, does it cause any memory leak or any other trouble (functionality-wise I handled it already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When a process is killed, the operating system releases all operating system resources (memory, sockets, file handles, …) previously acquired by that process.