# Python Testing with Kill Process

Tags: python, testing, process, kill

When testing a Python script I will often use a 'raw_input()' or 'input()' as a marker in the script, and when that marker is reached do a ctrl + c to kill the process in my command prompt.

I was worried this would lead to memory leaks, this brief thread indicates it shouldn't - [killing python process leads memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453194/php-python-killing-python-process-leads-memory-leak)

It is bad practice to test scripts this way?  Can it lead to any negative effects?

Comment: As with any good question, the right answer is *it depends*. In the simple case, you're fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP-Python - killing python process leads memory leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453194/php-python-killing-python-process-leads-memory-leak)

Comment: When you hit `ctrl + c` you get a `KeyboardInterrupt` Exception thrown. Then its the same as anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there's no problem with using `raw_input()` or `input()` with `ctrl` + `c` to terminate your program. When you press `ctrl`+ `c` during `raw_input` or `input` invocation you're just raising a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception and Python knows how to handle exceptions appropriately. If you don't handle the `KeyboardInterrupt`, this exception will be handled by the default top-level exception handler, this default exception handler prints the stack trace from which the exception occurred just before exiting the interpreter.

For some applications, they might not free their resources after they exit or after you kill the process, most operating systems today are smart enough to free memory when its unused. But this is not applicable to your question.

Comment: Once you start spawning new processes this general advice no longer holds.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the leaks but I'm sure breakpoints are your friend here. In idle right click on the line you want to stop on and click set breakpoint, then clear when you're finished debugging.